# How do Domain controllers discover each other for replication?

Tags: windows-server

When a DC is added to an existing domain, how does it find other DCs? If I where to configure replicate from any DC, how does the DC know how to find the other DCs? Is there a specific protocol that is used? Once they are found are they stored somewhere in the DC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first – using DNS, the same way as a member computer discovers DCs when joined. Your domain's DNS, specifically the `_msdcs` subdomain in newer versions, has various SRV records pointing to all usable domain controllers in each site.

Once the initial connection has been established, all Active Directory configuration is kept within AD itself. Each domain controller is also a member and has a regular 'Computer' object, but it also exists in "AD Sites & Services" (corresponding to CN=Sites,CN=Configuration in LDAP). Replication relationships are also kept in the same place.